# bokeh serve terminal print

Tags: python, bokeh

When I run `bokeh serve my_python_script.py` the print messages are not shown in the terminal. Is there a way to do this? For printing I use `print(message)`.

Comment: Are you ever actually opening a page that connects to the server? The Bokeh app code only runs *when a page is loaded*. Or, if your prints are in callbacks, are you sure the callbacks are ever getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end there was a hidden error in my code that was not handled properly. That was the reason of print not working